# ¿Cómo funciona Ajax en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo; que lo saque de este tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

> Hace una peticion a welcome.html, probe con otra url y no funciona.
>   ¿Por qué?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

    <h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

  </div>

  <p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("welcome.htm")
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El código está bien. ¿Tienes creado el archivo welcome.htm en la misma carpeta donde estas corriendo el archivo que has publicado?

Answer (score 1):

$http no es Ajax.

$http Es un Servicio de Angular.

> [$http is an AngularJS service for reading data from remote servers.](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

Con $http.GET, haces una petición GET a un Servidor. Por lo que la url que mandas por parametro tiene que existir y estar preparada para Recibir peticiones GET. 
   Si no entiendes de que hablo deberías seguir leyendo el artículo que dejaste de referencia, montar un servidor que pueda recibir Peticiones GET, y entonces hacer la peticion con $http para recibir algún Dato.

Te recomiendo leer éste blog que explica muy bien como hacer ésto creando un API REST:

[Blog](https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/tutorial-ejemplo-de-aplicacion-web-con-angular-js-y-api-rest-con-node/)

Comment: si revisas bien el link que colgue, ps trata de ajax

Answer (score 1):

En el metodo GET del servicio $http de angular se debe pasar la url de donde se desea obtener los datos.

```js
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [$scope, $http]);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("/urlDeTuApi")
        .success(function(response){
          $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        })
        .error(function(err){
          console.error(err);
        });
    });
 </script>
```